# Сравнительный оборот

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Если основное значение оборота - приравнивание или отождествление, то запятая перед *как* не ставится... Здесь этот случай?

Я готовился к выступлению как к взбиранию на скальную стену...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, именно этот случай, совершенно верно.

Comment: Я просто привела не все предложение...

Comment: А-а, понятно, не сообразил, тогда уберу этот вопрос за неактуальностью.)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, обычный сравнительный оборот. "Как" имеет значение "подобно".

Comment: А-а-а!!!! Niemand!!! Что же мне в самом деле делать?! А разве это не из разряда примеров: "Ты любил меня как собственность..." или "Он подавал свой камень как единственное, что он мог дать"?

Comment: Все примеры из Розенталя почерпнуты...

Comment: Думаю, это не из того разряда.